# What is the X and Y for the center of the screen? (haxeflixel)

Tags: haxeflixel

Im trying to get flxSprite to be in the center, but i dont wanna use the preset haxeflixel commands, since i might move it later, so can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

`(FlxG.width / 2, FlxG.height / 2)` Is the middle of the screen.

If you're going to place a FlxSprite in the middle of the screen, it should be `sprite.x = (FlxG.width / 2) - (sprite.width / 2)`, `sprite. y = (FlxG.height / 2) - (sprite.height / 2)`.

If you use `sprite.screenCenter();`, you will still be able to move it later. Unless you use it in your update function, of course.